# How to set value in charfield which is the value of previous charfield?

Tags: django

I was wondering if it is possible to set the value of another charfield automaticaly basing on previous choice ? I'm working on some simple movie-app and I need to change the colors of badge in html, basing on movie type. I would like to automate it instead of setting the collors manually. I'm kinda new in django. Basing on "kind" value I need to set the "color" value.

My Code:

```
AGE_CATEGORY = {
    ("0","All"),
    ("6","Kids"),
    ("16","Teenagers"),
    ("21","Adults")
}

MOVIE_CATEGORY = {
    ("H","Horror"),
    ("F","Fantasty"),
    ("ScI","Science-Fiction"),
    ("C","Comedy"),
    ("R","Romance"),
    ("T","Thriller"),
    ("D","Drama"),
}

MOVIE_CATEGORY_COLORS = {
    ("H","danger"),
    ("F","primary"),
    ("ScI","secondary"),
    ("C","warning"),
    ("R","success"),
    ("T","dark"),
    ("D","info"),
}
class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.CharField(choices=AGE_CATEGORY, max_length=2)
    kind = models.CharField(choices=MOVIE_CATEGORY, max_length=3)
    color = models.CharField(choices=MOVIE_CATEGORY_COLORS, max_length=1)
    price = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField()
    max_seats = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Found another solution :) Just created the new function in views and zipped 2 lists together - models and colors. Then just itterated thru them in html and seems to be working as expected. Posting it below, maybe someone will find it useful.

```
def show_all_movies(request):
    MOVIE_CATEGORY_COLORS = {
    ("H","danger"),
    ("F","primary"),
    ("ScI","secondary"),
    ("C","warning"),
    ("R","success"),
    ("T","dark"),
    ("D","info"),
}
    color_final = []
    for movie in Movies.objects.all():
        for color in MOVIE_CATEGORY_COLORS:
            if movie.kind in color:
                color_final.append(color[1])

    context = {
        "Movies_Colors": zip(Movies.objects.all(), color_final)

    }
    return render(request, "main_templates/movies.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) `save()` method with this functionality?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.kind is not None:
        self.color = self.kind
    super(Movies, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This should work if your choise keys of `kind` and `color` are equal

Comment: Doesn't work :C But I've found another solution :) thanks anyway